# Power Query - Merge queries returns true or false

Tags: merge, powerquery, m

I would like to know if it's possible with the M language to return only True or False if the merge between 2 queries match data or not ?

More or less, something similar to the ISNA function in Excel for the function VLOOKUP

Thanks

Comment: What is your broader goal with this? That is, what do you use the True/False information for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say I want to check what values in this table (`"firstTable"`):

[image: First table]

exist in this table below (`"secondTable"`):

[image: Second table]

**Approach 1**

If you only want to check for presence (and not actually perform a merge), then this might be one approach:

```
let
    firstTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,1)}, type table [column A=Int64.Type]),
    secondTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,2)}, type table [column B=Int64.Type]),
    check = Table.AddColumn(firstTable, "Is column A in column B?", each Table.Contains(secondTable, [column B = [column A]]), type logical)
in
    check
```

**Approach 2**

A similar but more verbose approach might be:

```
let
    firstTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,1)}, type table [column A=Int64.Type]),
    secondTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,2)}, type table [column B=Int64.Type]),
    check = Table.AddColumn(firstTable, "Is column A in column B?", each let colA = [column A], lookup = Table.MatchesAnyRows(secondTable, each [column B] = colA) in lookup, type logical)
in
    check
```

**Approach 3**

This approach will actually perform the merge, then check if each merged/joined table contains any rows. I would imagine it to be slower than the others (in theory as it will attempt to merge/match all rows and won't exit as soon as one match is found), but I might be wrong and it depends on `Table.Join`'s internal implementation.

```
let
    firstTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,1)}, type table [column A=Int64.Type]),
    secondTable = Table.FromColumns({List.Numbers(1,10,2)}, type table [column B=Int64.Type]),
    merged = Table.NestedJoin(firstTable, {"column A"}, secondTable, {"column B"}, "Is column A in the second table?", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    isEmpty = Table.TransformColumns(merged, {{"Is column A in the second table?", Table.IsEmpty, type logical}})
in
    isEmpty
```

I've given three approaches as you've not shown your data/example. It's difficult to suggest what will work well. But hopefully you can try them and one of them will be useful/performant for the size of your data.

Note that the first two lines (of each `M` snippet) are just to create some dummy tables `firstTable` and `secondTable`.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this might provide what you want, specifically using merge:

If I start with two tables from two different queries (my queries are named Query1 and Query2):

[image: Query1]  [image: Query2]

If I want to see which ones of Query2 are not in Query1, I click Home > Merge Queries > then I set up the dialog box like this and click OK:

[image]

Which gives me this:

[image]

Then I expand the tables in the Query2 column by clicking on [image]at the top right of the column to get this:

[image]

Then I click [image]at the left of the formula bar and type `= Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Query2", {"Column1.1", each if _ = null then false else true})` into the formula bar, and click enter to get this:

[image]

*(If you look at the right side of your screen, under **Applied Steps**, you'll see that Expanded Query2 was the previous step. Each step also happens to be a table state, like a query result is a table state. You can use those table states as tables, like you use query results as tables...because they basically are tables. This code transforms the column from that previous table state. Also, if you don't see the formula bar, click the View tab and check the Formula Bar box.)*

*****Added following @Frederic Le Guen's Comment*****

Here's a more direct way using List.Contains, which might be more in line with what you're looking for.

Starting with the same two tables from the same two queries as I did above, with the queries named Query1 and Query1 and Query2:

[image: Query1]  [image: Query2]

Go into Query1 and add a column to it -- Add Column > Custom Column -- and set it up like this:

[image]

and click OK.

You'll get this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks but I thought that is was possible to reach the same result with less steps.
If it's not possible, the solution is interesting

Comment: If you look into the List functions you may find something that better suits your true end goal.

Comment: I have tried a function like this `List.IsEmpty(List.FindText(myList, "string"))` but it's a very slow function. So I try to find a better way

Comment: I added another way that may be more in line with what you are looking for, at the end of my answer. It uses List.Contains.

Comment: My List.Contains example is basically the same as @Chillin's Approach 1.

Comment: Thanks for answer Marc.
Your solution is really simple and I didn't know I can use in this function the column of another query. I prefer to avoid merging queries when it's possible because it consumes so many memories